# NoneType has no attribute IF-ELSE solution

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing an HTML file and searching for status of order in it. Sometimes, status doesn't exist, so BeautifulSoup returns NoneType, when I'm using it. To solve this problem I use if-else statement, but it doesn't work too. Python returns:

> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

I am adding status to a dictionary, which contains other info from the order. The code below is a part, which adds new order's info to a dict.

```
database.append({
        "Title": title[0] + title.lower()[1:],
        "Name": name[0].upper() + name[1:],
        "Status": status.string[:len(status.string)-3] if status is not None else "Not listed",
        "Price": price
    })
```

Comment: Did you try inverting it? `"Not listed" if status is None else status.string[:len(status.string)-3]` I'm suspicious that python might be evaluating it anyway...

Comment: Are you sure you get error in _that_ code? http://ideone.com/N2U9Kl

Comment: Well I was wrong, non-reproducible it is then

Comment: also, `status.string[:-3] ` would do *exactly the same* as `status.string[:len(status.string)-3]`

Comment: It seems that status `is not None`, but `status.string` is...

Comment: @Jasper I've already tried this. In this case, Python says "NoneType has no string attribute"

Comment: What did you try exactly? It seems that you have to handle three cases: status is None / status is not None, but status.string is / status and status.string are both not None.

Comment: @Jasper if status.string is not None / if status is not None. Both solutions don't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be three cases:

1. `status` is None
2. `status is not None`, but `status.string` is
3. both `status` and `status.string` are `not None`

You have to provide code that handles each case.

```
if status is not None and status.string is not None:
     st = status.string[:-3]
else:
     st = "Not listed"

database.append({
        "Title": title[0] + title.lower()[1:],
        "Name": name[0].upper() + name[1:],
        "Status": st,
        "Price": price
    })
```

You can also stick the whole `if` in the dict if you prefer. You could also use exceptions:

```
try:
     st = status.string[:-3]
except (TypeError, AttributeError):
     st = "Not listed"
```