# if-else behavior returning tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

```
def pair_with_target_sum(nums: Sequence[int], target: int) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    x = _pair_with_target_sum(nums, target, 0, len(nums) - 1)
    return (nums[x[0]], nums[x[1]]) if x else x
```

Given that `_pair_with_target_sum` may return `None` or a `Tuple[int, int]`, the above code works as expected. However, if I remove the parentheses around the tuple in the return statement, and when `x` is `None`, the code fails with `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.

Why?.

Other relevant questions:

[Python tuple unpacking in return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47272460/839733)

[NoneType has no attribute IF-ELSE solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35418434/839733)

Comment: You can see how Python breaks down the code with https://github.com/alexmojaki/birdseye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nums[x[0]], nums[x[1]] if x else x` will be treated as:

```
nums[x[0]], (nums[x[1]] if x else x)
```

Proof:

```
>>> import ast
>>> root = ast.parse("nums[x[0]], nums[x[1]] if x else x")
>>> print(ast.dump(root, indent=1))
Module(
 body=[
  Expr(
   value=Tuple(
    elts=[
     Subscript(
      value=Name(id='nums', ctx=Load()),
      slice=Subscript(
       value=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()),
       slice=Constant(value=0),
       ctx=Load()),
      ctx=Load()),
     IfExp(
      test=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()),
      body=Subscript(
       value=Name(id='nums', ctx=Load()),
       slice=Subscript(
        value=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()),
        slice=Constant(value=1),
        ctx=Load()),
       ctx=Load()),
      orelse=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()))],
    ctx=Load()))],
 type_ignores=[])
>>>
```

As you can see, the elements of the tuple are `Subscript` (`nums[x[0]]`) and `IfExp`.

Apparently, `x is None`, but `nums[x[0]]` will attempt to index into it *anyway*.

Comment: In case of operator associativity and precedence, I can understand, but why does it associate this way?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, you can have a look at the [operator precedence table](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Comment: I have, there's nothing about comma or tuple in it. I'll accept your answer since it explains the behavior, but I'm curious as to why this behavior occurs.